# On PackedArray, looking for  advice for using them

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have not used PackedArray before, but just started looking at using them from reading some discussion on them here today.

What I have is lots of large size 1D and 2D matrices of all reals, and no symbolic (it is a finite difference PDE solver), and so I thought that I should take advantage of using PackedArray.

I have an initialization function where I allocate all the data/grids needed. So I went and used `ToPackedArray` on them. It seems a bit faster, but I need to do more performance testing to better compare speed before and after and also compare RAM usage.

But while I was looking at this, I noticed that some operations in M automatically return lists in PackedArray already, and some do not.

For example, this **does not** return packed array

```
a = Table[RandomReal[], {5}, {5}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[a]
```

But this **does**

```
a = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[a]
```

and this **does**

```
a = Table[0, {5}, {5}];
b = ListConvolve[ {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, a, 1];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[b]
```

and also matrix multiplication **does** return result in packed array

```
a = Table[0, {5}, {5}];
b = a.a;
Developer`PackedArrayQ[b]
```

But element wise multiplication **does not**

```
b = a*a;
Developer`PackedArrayQ[b]
```

My question : Is there a list somewhere which documents which M commands return PackedArray vs. not? (assuming data meets the requirements, such as Real, not mixed, no symbolic, etc..)

Also, a minor question, do you think it will be better to check first if a list/matrix created is already packed before calling calling `ToPackedArray` on it? I would think calling `ToPackedArray` on list already packed will not cost anything, as the call will return right away.

thanks,

**update (1)**

Just wanted to mention, that just found that PackedArray symbols not allowed in a demo CDF as I got an error uploading one with one. So, had to remove all my packing code out. Since I mainly write demos, now this topic is just of an academic interest for me. But wanted to thank everyone for time and good answers.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about PackedArray symbols not allowed in a demo CDF. Maybe with an example? This is of interest i think.

Comment: hi, I just made a small demo (demonstration style sheet, etc...) and just made a small Manipulate and used something like  `ToPackedArray[Table[0, {10}]]` in it, and then uploaded it my WRI authoring area to generate a demo CDF but the WRI uploader (which verifies demo files before uploading) rejected it saying that `PackedArray` symbol is not allowed. So basically this package is not allowed to be used in demos. You can try it yourself. I am sure there are good reasons why, security, support etc... but the bottom line, PackedArray can't be used in a WRI demonstration at least for now

Comment: ok so this looks like some sort of screening that Wolfram are doing rather than a blanket blocking of that function in CDF. That seems strange though.

Comment: It could be that this package (`Developer`) or parts of it, are not supported in the current version of the browser plugin. But I always test by uploading a demo I am working on whenever I add something new to it, or use a new build-in symbol, and such, to make sure it still would work in the plugin before I continue. I do not want to add 1,000 lines of code that depends on a function/symbol, then find later than this function is not supported ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a comprehensive list.  To point out a few things:

- Basic operations with packed arrays will tend to remain packed:

```
 
    In[66]:= a = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];

    In[67]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a, a.a, a*a}

    Out[67]= {True, True, True}
```

- Note above that that my version (8.0.4) doesn't unpack for element-wise multiplication.
- Whether a `Table` will result in a packed array depends on the number of elements:

```
 
    In[71]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ[Table[RandomReal[], {24}, {10}]]

    Out[71]= False

    In[72]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ[Table[RandomReal[], {24}, {11}]]

    Out[72]= True

    In[73]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ[Table[RandomReal[], {25}, {10}]]

    Out[73]= True
```

- `On["Packing"]` will turn on messages to let you know when things unpack:

```
 
    In[77]:= On["Packing"]

    In[78]:= a = RandomReal[1, 10];

    In[79]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ[a]

    Out[79]= True

    In[80]:= a[[1]] = 0 (* force unpacking due to type mismatch *)

       Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {10}. >>

    Out[80]= 0
```

- Operations that do per-element inspection will usually unpack the array,

```
    In[81]:= a = RandomReal[1, 10];

    In[82]:= Position[a, Max[a]]

       Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to Position. >>

    Out[82]= {{4}}
```

- There penalty for calling `ToPackedArray` on an already packed list is small enough that I wouldn't worry about it too much:

```
    In[90]:= a = RandomReal[1, 10^7];

    In[91]:= Timing[Do[Identity[a], {10^5}];]

    Out[91]= {0.028089, Null}

    In[92]:= Timing[Do[Developer`ToPackedArray[a], {10^5}];]

    Out[92]= {0.043788, Null}
```

- The frontend prefers packed to unpacked arrays, which can show up when dealing with `Dynamic` and `Manipulate`:

```
    In[97]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ[{1}]

    Out[97]= False

    In[98]:= Dynamic[Developer`PackedArrayQ[{1}]]

    Out[98]= True
```

- When looking into performance, focus on cases where large lists are getting unpacked, rather than the small ones.  Unless the small ones are in big loops.

Comment: When I used `On["packing"]` I see now lots of messages come out to the console now when I run my demo. Like this `FromPackedArray::punpackl1: Unpacking array with dimensions {5,5,2} to level 2.` But with no line numbers and nothing else, I need to find if there is an easy way to find from where these are coming and see if I can change the code so things do not get unpacked? Just messages with no help from M as from where they came out is not too useful. I have 7,000 lines of code. But it is a start.  I have more work to do now :) thanks

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi, profile your code, find the functions that consume most time, fix those first; I am sure you do not have one function with 7KLines of code ;-)

Comment: @ruebenko, thanks but I do not know how to profile code in M. It is ONE big cell. This is a demo, and it is ONE big Manipulate cell. I do not know how to use workbench to run Manipulate. It also depends on the UI input, the code runs different path. But the point is, if M will simply tell at least the function name in which the error came from, it would help. No line number and nothing else, the messages are pretty useless for me, since hard to know from where they came.

Answer (score 7):

This is just an addendum to [Brett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775543/421225):

```
SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]
```

will give you the lengths being used for which a function will return a packed array. So if you did need to pack a small list, as an alternative to using `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` you could temporarily set a smaller number for one of the compile options. e.g.

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 20}]
```

Note also some difference between functions which to me at least doesn't seem intuitive so I generally have to test these kind of things whenever I use them rather than instinctively knowing what will work best:

```
f = # + 1 &;
g[x_] := x + 1;
data = RandomReal[1, 10^6];

On["Packing"]
Timing[Developer`PackedArrayQ[f /@ data]]
{0.131565, True}


Timing[Developer`PackedArrayQ[g /@ data]]
Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {1000000}.
{1.95083, False}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another addition to Brett's answer: If a list is a packed array then a ToPackedArray is very fast since this checked quite early. Also you might find this valuable:

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/3141/

In general for numerics stuff look for talks from Rob Knapp and/or Mark Sofroniou.

When I develop numerics codes, I write the function and then use On["Packing"] to make sure that everything is packed that needs to be packed.

Concerning Mike's answer, the threshold has been introduced since for small stuff there is overhead. Where the threshold is is hardware dependent. It might be an idea to write a function that sets these threshold based on measurements done on the computer.

Comment: Could I make another plea for a method for packing of DateLists to be introduced. Date and time functions are embarrassingly slow in Mma relative to other products.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, I think you are best of to send such requests to support@wolfram.com; such that the appropriate developer see these requests.

Comment: Unfortunately WRI have known about this for years. A minor improvement in speed occured in V8 -- a few % -- when what is needed is 50-100 times improvement. I don't think it is taken seriously because they seem to think in terms of one off prototyping calculations -- where the slowness is not so noticeable -- rather than large scale batch production work -- where it is often the rate limiting step. So it gets down to a difference in emphasis/focus of developers vs users I think. BTW when I add @Ruebenko or another name at the start it gets chopped off when I save.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, could you send me an example (ruebenkoPPPwolfram.com) I can then look at it;  but this is not my turf and I can not guarantee anything.

Comment: Here is an example that a user has previously posted on Mathgroup http://www.wheels.org/monkeywrench/?p=453. More generally I find that I write my own functions and can get up to e.g. 30-80 speed improvement without too much trouble. As per the link this is generally when you know your date format so it seems a lot of the overhead for these functions is in the pre-screening or whatever takes place internally initially. Nevertheless, given the fixed format of date lists I would think they are good candidates for developing a means of packing them.

Comment: I filed this as a suggestion (there was none). But I can not say anything about if or when this will be addressed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6562/discussion-between-mike-honeychurch-and-ruebenko)